# casting error on binding dictionary to repeater asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, casting, repeater

I am trying to populate `<li>` items with a repeater, binding it to a Dictionary object. I have a dictionary called cart, with standard Key, Value properties.

**I get a runtime error:**

```
`System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`
```

**I used this code:**

```
<ItemTemplate>
<li id="<%# ((KeyValuePair<string,string>)Container.DataItem).Key %>_i" >
<%# ((KeyValuePair<string,string>)Container.DataItem).Key %> <%# ((KeyValuePair<string,string>)Container.DataItem).Value %>
</li></ItemTemplate>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Your ItemTemplate works for me when binding to a `Dictionary<string, string>`. Are you sure that the error is related to the binding in the ItemTemplate? Do you have an OnItemDataBound Event handler? Is the type of the dictionary `Dictionary<string, string>`? Can you add the StackTrace of the error?

Comment: Markus thanks for checking my code, you are correct the error is not related to the ItemTemplate. By mistake I set the DataSource to the dictionary's values instead of the dictionary itself. thanks much! It works now!

Comment: @user26333600: Good to hear that it works. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ItemTemplate works for me when binding to a `Dictionary<string, string>`. Therefore, I'd suggest to check whether the Repeater is really bound to a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

If not, the exception makes sense and can be solved by fixing the data binding code (or changing the type that is used in the ItemTemplate so that it matches the data that is bound to the Repeater.

Answer (score 0):

if your Dictionary is not a `Dictionary<string, string>` you can do something like

```
((System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,byte[]>)(Container.DataItem)).Key
```

Or

```
((System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<clsProduct,int>)(Container.DataItem)).Key.ProductCode
```